# How do I prove that there exist infinite number of primes satisfying the given condition

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

$\DeclareMathOperator\ord{ord}$For any natural numbers $a$ and $b$ prove that there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\ord_p(a) = \ord_p(b)$

How do I prove this. The solution makes use of some Kobayashi's theorem. However I do not know what it is can anyone help me with this question

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  Any prime greater than $\max (a,b)$ works, no?

Comment: How can that be proved?

Comment: For natural numbers, if $a$ divides $b$ then $a≤b$.

Comment: Yeah it works for the case when $a$ divides $b$. What if they are co-prime?

Comment: What?  If $p>\max (a,b)$ then $p>a$ and $p>b$ so $p$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$.